# Intergenic Regions?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a bed file with genes on the plus and minus strands. I want to get the intergenic regions between the genes on the positive and negative strands. Is there any way to do this with an awk command? Thanks so much!

Edit: The second and third columns are gene start and stop sites. Basically I want to subtract the number in the third column and the number in the preceding second row if there is a + sign starting from the bottom. If the last column has a - sign I also want to start from the bottom but subtract the number in the second column and the number in the preceding third row.

Desired output

```
chr1  820983    (860759-820983)    ENSG00000269308 591    +
chr1   818542     (818542-369634)   ENSG00000235249 587   +
ch1 738637     (738637-623056)      ENSG00000185097 589   -
ch1 621546     (621546-140379)      ENSG00000237683  586 -
```

Input

```
chr1    13885   140379  ENSG00000237683 586 -
chr1    36854   369634  ENSG00000235249 587 +    
chr1    621546  623056  ENSG00000185097 589 -    
chr1    738637  740137  ENSG00000269831 590 -    
chr1    818542  820983  ENSG00000269308 591 +   
chr1    860759  875671  ENSG00000187634 591 +
```

Comment: um... excuse my ignorance, but which bits are the intergenic regions? Show us your desired output :)

Comment: As well as the input! Where are the DNA sequences? Anyway, I doubt awk can help to edit DNA sequences. Intergenic regions won't have any defined length or composition.

Comment: Yes, there is, but you need to express your question so that people who have no idea what a bed file, a chromosome, a +/- strand or any other bioinformatics concept is. This is not a site for bioinformaticians, so you need to express this as a simple text parsing question.

Comment: How do 6 lines of input yield 4 lines of output? How do we know which ones to discard?

Comment: The only two numbers that don't get used are the first one in the second column and the last one in the third column.

Comment: Will post awk answer, hope I'm quick :  )

Comment: @KasiyA do it :)

Comment: I'm still finding it hard to understand the rules you've put in place for creating your output. Can you clarify which line the + or - symbol should be on to have each effect. It also seems like the word column and row are being used interchangeably. I could just be being dim, but it would help to separate the steps to take in each case.

Comment: I'm using row and column to specify the coordinate of the number. The plus symbol means to take the number in the bottom row/second column and subtract the number in the next plus row above it from the third column. And so on until the top row is reached. The minus symbol means to take the number in the bottom row/third column and subtract the number in the next plus row above it from the second column.

Comment: I *think* I get it - all except why the number in the 2nd column is equal to the first number in brackets for all except the first row of your output (i.e. why is that 820983 rather than 860759?)

Comment: Those are the numbers I want to subtract

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand your explanation and desired output completely (why are some column 1 values `chr1` and some `ch1`? why is column 2 in the first row 820983 rather than 860759?), however this may be enough to get you started.

If you don't care about the order of output, the simplest thing would seem to be to reverse the order of lines in the file, an then simply keep a rolling record of the most recent column 2 values for the `+` and `-` entries, and print/subtract them when the next `+` or `-` is encountered:

```
$ tac file.bed | awk '
>   $NF ~ /+/ {if(last2p) print $1, last2p, "(" last2p "-" $3 ")", $4, $5, $6; last2p = $2}
>   $NF ~ /-/ {if(last2m) print $1, last2m, "(" last2m "-" $3 ")", $4, $5, $6; last2m = $2}
> '
chr1 860759 (860759-820983) ENSG00000269308 591 +
chr1 738637 (738637-623056) ENSG00000185097 589 -
chr1 818542 (818542-369634) ENSG00000235249 587 +
chr1 621546 (621546-140379) ENSG00000237683 586 -
```

If you *do* care about the output order, then you can construct a pair of arrays `plus` and `minus` say, then iterate over them in reverse looking "up" for the next matching `+` or `-`.  This is too big for a one-liner so presented here as an executable awk script:

```
$ cat chr.awk
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

function fooprint(a,i, j,p,q) {
  split(a[i], p);
  for(j=i-1;j>0;j--) {
    if(j in a) {
      split(a[j], q);
      print q[1], p[2], "(" p[2] "-" q[3] ")", q[4], q[5], q[6];
      break;
    }
  }
}

$NF ~ /+/ {plus[FNR] = $0}
$NF ~ /-/ {minus[FNR] = $0}

END {
  for(i=NR; i>1; i--) {
    if (i in plus)
      fooprint(plus,i);
    else if (i in minus)
      fooprint(minus,i);
  }
}
```

then

```
$ ./chr.awk file.bed
chr1 860759 (860759-820983) ENSG00000269308 591 +
chr1 818542 (818542-369634) ENSG00000235249 587 +
chr1 738637 (738637-623056) ENSG00000185097 589 -
chr1 621546 (621546-140379) ENSG00000237683 586 -
```